# iPhone and Cocoa targets in one Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I'm having troubles converting Xcode project containing iPhone target to add Cocoa application. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Whether on StackOverflow or the Apple forums, you'll get a better response if you post a specific question with technical detail, describe what you tried, the results you got, and how they differ from what you want.  Open-ended "help me" questions do not usually elicit useful answers, because we don't know what the problem is.